How to avoid infinite recursion issue in GraphQL resolver for many-to-many relationship?
schema.graphql:
scalar Score

type Player {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    rating: Int!
    matches: [Match!]!
}

enum MatchStatus {
    ONGOING
    COMPLETED
    CANCELLED
}

type Match {
    id: ID!
    players: [Player!]!
    score: Score!
    status: MatchStatus!
}

type Query {
    players: [Player!]!
    player(id: ID!): Player
    matches: [Match!]!
    match(id: ID!): Match
}

schema.prisma:
model Player {
  id      String  @id @default(cuid())
  name    String
  rating  Int
  matches Match[]
}

model Match {
  id      String   @id @default(cuid())
  score   String
  status  String
  players Player[]
}

The above are my GraphQL schema and Prisma schema. As you can see, there is a many-to-many relationship between Player and Match.
I'm using graphql-codegen to help me generate TypeScript types from my GraphQL schema. This also allows me to type my resolver map to ensure type safety when writing my resolvers.
However, I'm having trouble writing a resolver for Query.players and Query.matches. Because of the many-to-many relationship between Player and Match, an infinite recursion issue arises. For example, for Query.players, if I use prisma.player.findMany() to get all players, the compiler will complain that matches is missing. If I include matches in the findMany() call, then it will complain that the includes matches is missing players and so on.
e.g.
"Property 'matches' is missing in type '{ id: string; name: string; rating: number; }' but required in type 'Player'."

How do I avoid this?

Showing what you have tried so far is helpful. How do your attempts at resolvers look like? What kind of queries have you written? Also, what is your DB provider?
